# Swift - How to use viewForAnnotation for simple round corner image?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I want to create basic profile image annotation instead default annotation pin, but I don't know how to use viewForAnnotation in this case.

Is there a way to create a xib file like tableView header-footer view? Or what is the great choice to create this simply.

If someone would explain these possible ways with How Can I use viewForAnnotation for that. It would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much effort, so I am inclined to not answer, but here you go.

Create a xib, and set it up. Create a class that inherits from UIView

Add the class to the view.[image]

Add the File Owner as the ViewController that handles the Map/Annotations.
[image]

Setup the View and anything that you might want to add in here. Connect your outlets to the View's Class that you created. Then in the file you assigned as the Files Owner:

```
//create view in code from xib
let annotation = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("XibFileName", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as? AnnotationClassName

//setup view
annotation.randomLabelOrPropertyOrDelegate = theValueYouWantToAssignItToSetupTheView

//assign the view
viewForAnnotation = annotation
```

The last thing to consider is the size of the annotation. If you constrain an imageView to the edges of the Xib's main View, then the annotation will be whatever size that your image is. The other option is to set up the frame yourself, although the constraints in your xib file will have to allow it to have the given frame. This would be done like so

```
annotation.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: desiredWidth, height: desiredHeight)
```